# Macro not seen by header

Tags: c, macros, c-preprocessor

How can I use a macro as a function (declared in header - macro in source)? 
I'm looking for something like this (except that this one doesn't work)...

**Foo.h:**

```
#ifndef FOO_H
#define FOO_H

struct bar;

int bar_isEmpty(struct bar *b);

#endif /* !defined FOO_H */
```

**Foo.c:**

```
struct bar {
   size_t numElements;
};

#define bar_isEmpty(bar) {bar->numElements == 0}
```

As you can see, I can't put the macro in the header, since the structure isn't defined there.

Comment: Can you provide the definition of _"doesn't work"_?

Comment: I guess you cannot do such a thing. Why not define the macro in the header or define normal function is the source file?

Comment: Why not move the structure and macro to the header file?

Comment: @AshishAhujaツ I get `Undefined symbols`.

Comment: @MikeCAT Because the struct is defined in the source. The header isn't able to see `numElements`.

Comment: @EdHeal Because the use doesn't have to see the implementation.

Comment: A macro definition doesn't need to access anything else. You just have to take care of it usage, not its definition.

Comment: that macro does not make any sense whatsoever. Perhaps you wanted to at least say `(!bar->numElements)`

Comment: The curly braces you are using inside the macro are the issue *Antti* is referring to.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you do not want to expose `struct bar` to outside the object, there as well is no way to expose a marco to the outside using the latter (the `struct bar`).

This is by definition as a macro is simply sort of a text replacement which is applied **before** compiling the result of all macro expansions.

---

BTW, in C this

```
int bar_isEmpty(bar *b);
```

won't compile and needs to be

```
int bar_isEmpty(struct bar *b);
```

Comment: Thanks, that is what I was looking for. The missing *struct* was a mistake though. Will fix.

Answer (score 2):

There's a few problems with your posted code.

First of all there's little reason to define the macro in the first place. Your header contains a prototype for a function and that indicates that `bar_isEmpty` should be defined as a function. Every c-file that includes the header file would be able to make use of `bar_isEmpty` and therefore it should be defined as a function. So your c-file should look something like:

```
#include <stddef.h>
#include "foo.h"

struct bar {
   size_t numElements;
};

int bar_isEmpty(struct bar* b) {
    return b->numElements == 0;
}
```

Second is that you didn't include `foo.h` (which I've corrected above). Third is that `size_t` need to be defined - which can be done by including `stddef.h` (also done in the example above).

Defining it as a macro is OK **if** you intent to use it only in `foo.c` or if the struct is fully defined in the header file. The actual definition of the macro is no problem, the problem arises when you invoke the macro. On the other hand you should probably not provide a prototype in the header file in that case. A macro is just a rule of text replacement so your macro is badly defined as `bar_isEmpty(something)` would expand to `{ b->numElements == 0 }` which is not valid syntax anywhere. Probably the correct definition in this case would be:

```
#define bar_isEmpty(b) ((b)->numElements == 0)
```